# Benefits of higher order low pass in a negative feedback loop

Tags: control-system, pid-controller, bandwidth, pll, loop-gain

Let \$G(s) = \frac{Y(s)}{R(s)}\$ be the loop gain of a negative feedback loop system.

> For example a system like this, where Y(s) and R(s) are the laplace
>   transformed functions y(t) and r(t):
>
> [image]

At the loop bandwith \$\omega_0\$ \$|G(i\omega_0)|\$ becomes unity. Why is it now benefical to have a roll-off (for \$\omega>\omega_0\$) as steep as possible? For example in a PLL you often find several low pass filters in the loop filter:

[image]

Comment: The question doesn't seem to make sense because it's certainly not the case that the frequency response should be as steep as possible past the natural resonant frequency. Please clarify your question.

Comment: Could you explain why?

Comment: It's called phase margin - too steep means instability when the loop is closed.

Comment: Sure. You want to have a phase margin above 45° or so when crossing unity. But afterwards you want a steep roll-off right? In my question I was refering to this region

Comment: No, I don't see the general case at all. If it rolls off at 60 dB/dec beyond \$\omega_0\$ or carries on at a lower rate there is no general problem. The PLL comparison is a flawed argument.

Comment: But why are R2 and C3 used at all? Without them G would have an 40db roll-off. With R2 and C3 it is a 60dB roll-off. There must be a reason for this

Comment: If your question is really about PLL filters why did you pre-empt it with a question about control systems that appears to be irrelevant? You cannot compare the two filters especially when the PLL phase output is a square wave. It's like asking why we don't put in an LC low pass filter on a linear voltage regulator based on the fact the switching regulators use them.

Comment: Indeed, I'm especially interested in the case of a PLL. However, I thought that "the steeper the roll-off the better" would be statement valid for all kind of negative feedback systems. But what is the answer for PLLs now?

Comment: Well you've made a mess of this question so I would advise you to leave it as it is (so as not to piss off anyone who has already made answers) and ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one reason: in a real system, some features of the plant such as mechanical resonances of actuators may be present at frequencies *above* the unity gain frequency defined by the control law, which should not be driven by the feedback. For example, some types of mechanical resonance (e.g. from piezoelectric transducers) have high quality factor, which focus oscillation in narrow frequency bands when energy is provided to drive the oscillation. While with a low pass filter the majority of the plant's deviation from the set point would be suppressed below the controller's unity gain frequency (as defined by the low pass filter in this case), sharp mechanical resonances must not be driven to the extent that they resonate with a magnitude that again crosses the unity gain frequency. In such a case, if the phase at the resonant frequency is close to an odd multiple of 180°, the system can oscillate and become unstable.

A single low pass filter provides suppression above the corner frequency inverse to frequency. Using a higher order low pass filter allows the magnitude of the feedback to be further suppressed at higher frequencies (for a second order filter, by inverse frequency squared, and so on). Higher order low pass filters therefore help to prevent "ringing up" resonant features that can create instabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Do not confuse a hardware feedback loop such as a PLL, which needs a very fast correction factor (intergral), with a servo-loop that controls a slow mechanical device, such as a motor.

A PLL needs no derivative feedback, while a motor needs it for sudden changes in load or speed, then the integral dominates during study speed or study loads.

High-order integrals are best used in frequency-hopping communications gear, which allows for FM and FSK transmissions. There is a maximum time to change frequency bands before the loop tries to stabilize the frequency.

Other than that type of use high-order LPF are seldom used, as they cause too much delay in the correction time, such as a single frequency PLL.

Comment: Correct reference to frequency hopping. These applications use higher loop bandwidth to assure short settling time. This makes them prone to PLL-reference spurs. Third order filter is used to better suppress these spurs.